# Is it possible to download test data with real label from Kaggle competition?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, kaggle

For the Kaggle competitions that entail classification problems, a train and test dataset are given. Train data is labeled, but test data is not labeled. It only contains sample data and the model is checked on Kaggle servers and an accuracy or f1 score is returned. I guess that Kaggle compares its own labeled test data with your submission. Is there a way to download the file with labeled test data from Kaggle?

Comment: no, that's the entire point of the challenge. You don't know the test label. I m not sure if they disclose it at the end but you can try to guess the structure of the test by doing multiple tests. For example, the score of a file with only 0 will tell you the distribution for an accuracy base competition.

Comment: Test labels are not released. This is actually a good thing, because it allows the datasets to be used as benchmarks also after the competition has ended.

Comment: In cases that you need these data for your own project, you can manually split the original train data into train and test data.